# (discord.py) bot has no attribute error when trying to call a user-defined function

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add an economy system to my discord bot written in python. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPaadO_sRD4) on youtube and implemented it into my code. This is what it looks like:

```
from discord.ext import commands

import json
import os

class Eco(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  #function to get bank data
  async def getbankdata(self):

    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)

    return users
  
  #function to open a new account for a user if they don't have one
  async def open_account(self, user):

    users = await self.client.getbankdata(self)

    if str(user.id) in users:
      return False
    else:
      users[str(user.id)] = {}
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
      users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users, f)
      
    return True

  #check balance command
  @commands.command()
  async def bal(self, ctx):

    user = ctx.author
    await self.open_account(user)
    users = await self.getbankdata()

    walletamt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bankamt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    await ctx.send(f'Wallet: {walletamt}, Bank: {bankamt}')

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Eco(client))
```

In the tutorial, all the code was written in the main.py file, where here I wrote all the code in a cog file, so i had to tweak the functions a bit. When ever i try to run the `bal` command i get an error saying that `'Bot' object has no attribute 'getbankdata'`. I can't seem to find the source of the error. Can someone help me? I would also appreciate any other corrections in my code that might raise an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the `open_account` method. It's not `self.client.getbankdata`, it's `self.getbankdata`

```py
async def open_account(self, user):
    users = self.getbankdata()
    # ...
```

Comment: i fixed the code and it works now... when i tried that before it said that getbankdata was undefined. thanks.

Comment: No worries, remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: It's undefined as your balance command is after the opening account function, try putting it about the getbankdata and open_account